# Configuring class autoloading in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

there is a [project on Github](https://github.com/wnull/userbars-warface-generator) that works stably. Below is a composer file:

```
{
    "name": "wnull/userbars-warface-generator",
    "description": "Simple and free library to generate userbars game Warface",
    "keywords": [
        "wf",
        "warface",
        "generator",
        "userbars"
    ],
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "WF\\": "src/WF"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after each successful installation of the project through the composer, you have to do the following command:

```
>>> composer dump-autoload -o
```

After that, all all classes will work correctly. Log from the console:

```
C:\hangry>composer require wnull/userbars-warface-generator
Using version ^1.0 for wnull/userbars-warface-generator
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing wnull/userbars-warface-generator (v1.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

C:\hangry>
C:\hangry>composer dump-autoload -o
Generated optimized autoload files containing 6 classes
```

Question: how do I avoid entering this command every time, and everything worked correctly during normal installation?

Comment: It could be because you're using the `-o` flag. From the manual about that flag: _"Convert PSR-0/4 autoloading to classmap to get a faster autoloade"_. If you're on in development environment, you don't need that flag. That flag mostly make sense in production.

Comment: Why do you think you need to run `composer dump-autoload -o` command?

Comment: @rob006, Because after it, the project works. I do not find other options, can you tell me something?

Comment: I see no reason why project should not work without this command, and you didn't provide any error message. So why do you think it will not work without this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by replacing the `PSR-4` to `classmap`. Thanks @MagnusEriksson.

Composer file:

```
{
    "name": "wnull/userbars-warface-generator",
    "description": "Simple and free library to generate userbars game Warface",
    "keywords": [
        "wf",
        "warface",
        "generator",
        "userbars"
    ],
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/WF"]
    }
}
```